# xprop fails to undecorate window

Tags: xorg, window-manager, window-decoration, xprop

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. I want to undecorate (remove borders and title bar) of a window. I found an old posted scripts on the net claimed to be working but it doesn't work now.

**To undecorate:**

```
xprop -f _MOTIF_WM_HINTS 32c -set _MOTIF_WM_HINTS "0x2, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0"
```

**To redecorate:**

```
xprop -f _MOTIF_WM_HINTS 32c -set _MOTIF_WM_HINTS "0x2, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0"
```

Though this python script works

```
#! /usr/bin/python2
import gtk.gdk
w = gtk.gdk.window_foreign_new( gtk.gdk.get_default_root_window().property_get("_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW")[2][0] )
w.set_decorations( (w.get_decorations()+1)%2 ) # toggle between 0 and 1
gtk.gdk.window_process_all_updates()
gtk.gdk.flush()
```

How can I toggle window decoration from terminal without python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will not work in compiz! Compiz expects that `_MOTIF_WM_HINTS` property type is `_MOTIF_WM_HINTS`, but `xprop` command sets it to `CARDINAL`. If you use `xprop | grep _MOTIF_WM_HINTS` you will see this:

> _MOTIF_WM_HINTS(CARDINAL) = 2, 0, 0, 0, 0

It should be like this:

> _MOTIF_WM_HINTS(_MOTIF_WM_HINTS) = 2, 0, 0, 0, 0

Your python script works, because GTK+ properly sets this property. :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Would you post it as a whole liner? I got error with this `xprop -f _MOTIF_WM_HINTS 32c -set _MOTIF_WM_HINTS(_MOTIF_WM_HINTS) = 2, 0, 0, 0, 0`

Comment: You can not change property type! This might be fixed in compiz, see [merge proposal](https://code.launchpad.net/~muktupavels/compiz/motif-wm-hints/+merge/326777).

Comment: And [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1702297) is bug report. :) Subscribe to get notified when this gets fixed.

Comment: Do you know any way to undecorate a window with other tools such as `wmctrl`

Comment: No, I don't... But what are you trying to do? Should not be hard to write small command-line app that can toggle decorations. My fix most likely will be available in 16.04. :)

Comment: It would be satisfactory for me if  there was a `c` program which accepts `process id` or `window id` to toggle the decoration

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/muktupavels/d03bb14ea6042b779df89b4c87df975d) is small program that will do that, you need to compile it first.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61602/discussion-between-kenn-and-muktupavels).